# MySQL FULLTEXT won't work with more than one field

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a bog standard MySQL fulltext query as follows:

`SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE MATCH(first_name, username) AGAINST ('stringhere')`

The problem is, it can't find the fulltext index on the field `first_name`, even though I've indexed it a few times now. It works fine when I do this:

`SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE MATCH(username) AGAINST ('stringhere')`

Or this:

`SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE MATCH(first_name) AGAINST ('stringhere')`

But not with two or more fields. What am I doing wrong here? I've made sure the indexes are set on the fields, and I've even REPAIRed the table, but still no worky :-(

I get this result when using more than one field:

`Error in query: Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list`

Which is confusing and irritating because, like I said, I have definitely defined the fulltext index.

Thanks for any help,

James

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be useful to see the output of

```
show create table accounts
```

I suppose that you have something like

```
FULLTEXT(first_name)
FULLTEXT(username)
```

instead of

```
FULLTEXT(first_name,username)
```

Comment: Right you are: `FULLTEXT KEY `username` (`username`), FULLTEXT KEY `first_name` (`first_name`)`. I added all the fields I needed and it works great now. Thanks!

Comment: You have to list all the columns you want to include in your fulltext searches as I wrote you in the last line of my answer. Remove your indexes and re-create a new one in the right way.